# Dozer custom converter applies on all fields

Tags: java, dozer

I just declared the following converter

```
<converter type="co.mine.converter.ProductToNameConverter">
          <class-a>java.lang.String</class-a>
          <class-b>java.lang.String</class-b>
</converter>
```

and in the mapping file:

```
<field custom-converter="co.mine.converter.ProductToNameConverter">
        <a>productId</a>
        <b>product</b>
</field>
```

but for every mapping field, where source is `String` and destination is `String` also, this converter has been called. So how should I avoid such behavior? In other words, I only want that converter to work on `productId` and `product`.

Comment: Hi @Khodabakhsh if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and up-voting it. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the converter to work only for `productId` and `product` your second configuration is enough. Remove the first.